# F# implicit typing choking on simple recursion

Tags: recursion, syntax, f#, implicit-typing

When I define a recursive function in F# thus:

```
let rec recursiveSum inputs =
    let startState = 0.0m

    if List.length inputs = 1 then
        startState + inputs.Head
    else
        let t = List.tail inputs
        startState + inputs.Head + recursiveSum t
```

...all is good. When I attempt to avoid the "empty list" problem thus:

```
let rec recursiveSum inputs =
    let startState = 0.0m

    **if List.isEmpty inputs then startState**

    if List.length inputs = 1 then
        startState + inputs.Head
    else
        let t = List.tail inputs
        startState + inputs.Head + recursiveSum t
```

...I get yelled at:

```
recursion.fsx(5,9): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    unit    
but here has type
    decimal
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/conditional-expressions-if-then-else):

> The types of the values produced in each branch must match. If there is no explicit `else` branch, its type is `unit`. Therefore, if the type of the `then` branch is any type other than `unit`, there must be an `else` branch with the same return type.

You're missing said `else`.

```
let rec recursiveSum inputs =
    let startState = 0.0m

    if List.isEmpty inputs then 0.0m
    elif List.length inputs = 1 then
        startState + inputs.Head
    else
        let t = List.tail inputs
        startState + inputs.Head + recursiveSum t
```

(N.b. I've used `elif` here rather than nesting another `if` expression; hopefully that's not too much of a distraction.)

That said, your logic involving `startState` is highly suspect; it's always zero, and really serves no purpose here. Your state should probably be a parameter rather than a local value so it can be used as an accumulator:

```
let recursiveSum inputs =
    let rec impl state inputs =
        if List.isEmpty inputs then state
        elif List.length inputs = 1 then
            state + inputs.Head
        else
            let t = List.tail inputs
            impl (state + inputs.Head) t
    impl 0.0m inputs
```

Lastly, let's make it idiomatic:

```
let recursiveSum inputs =
    let rec impl state inputs =
        match inputs with
          | []   -> state
          | [h]  -> state + h
          | h::t -> impl (state + h) t
    impl 0.0m inputs
```

which can be shortened to

```
let recursiveSum inputs =
    let rec impl state = function
      | []   -> state
      | h::t -> impl (state + h) t
    impl 0.0m inputs
```

Comment: Great answer, really appreciate that you answered the question in close-to-original format AND provided the "idiomatic" example. For newbs like me, it's a big help.

Comment: To answer YOUR question, the startState was only provided as a "hint" to the type inference engine, and is not important to the result. I haven't yet read enough to fully understand your "idiomatic" answer, but I'm only halfway through the book so I'll print it and review when I have better knowledge.

Comment: @Duncan  : I added another step before the final idiomatic solution in case `function` is a point of confusion. Note that you can make this function work with _any_ numeric type by marking it [`inline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/functions/inline-functions) and using [`LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/languageprimitives.genericzero%5B%5Et%5D-type-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) in place of `0.0m`. :-]

Comment: thanks, I am still not fluent reading, so could not parse the "empty list" and "list of one element" and "head plus tail" forms. Having figured it out, I am even more eager to learn this language -- so terse, yet so powerful.

As an aside, any book recommendations will be gratefully received (I'm an autodidact, in case that leads you to another resource).

Comment: @Duncan : Likewise! I mostly learned the language from Don Syme's 'Expert F#' book, but it's not my first functional language and I can't say for sure that that book covers the basics well as I mostly skimmed the first section. [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/) has some **excellent** articles, especially the Railway Oriented Programming series if you're not already monad-minded. Lastly, there are a few critical 3rd party libraries that should be whole-heartedly embraced: FSharpx, FSharp.Data, and for performance-minded code, Nessos.Streams and Hopac.

Answer (score 2):

With ildjarns answer, I think I would suggest that one could/should go all the way...

```
let rec fold f acc = function 
        | [] -> acc
        | [x] -> f x acc
        | h::t -> fold f (f h acc) t




let someDec = [0.1m; 0.2m]
let someStr = ["world"; "Hello "]

someDec
|> fold (+) 0.0m

someStr
|> fold (+) ""


let recursiveSum = fold (+) 0.0m    

someDec
|> recursiveSum


let recursiveStrAdd = fold (+) ""

someStr
|> recursiveStrAdd


someDec
|> recursiveSum
```

(And I never remember left or right here, so... ;-)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!